# Rails migration default 0 is not false?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

In the migration file I have:

```
class AddEnabledToJob < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :jobs, :enabled, :boolean, default: 0
  end
end
```

But then in my view I'm looking for every `:enabled => false` object:

```
<% @jobs.where(enabled: false).order("id DESC").each do |job| %>
```

This doesn't work. It works if I change it to:

```
<% @jobs.where(enabled: 0).order("id DESC").each do |job| %>
```

And this is confusing since I'm changing the `enabled` value to `false` somewhere else in my application so I have some Job objects with `enabled: false` and some with `enabled: 0`. How can I correct this and why does it happen?

**EDIT:**

To expand on this issue I have populated all Jobs (`Job.all`) via the console and I see that the while the new records are created with `default: 0` they have a value of `false`. So why is `@jobs.where(enabled: false)` failing to retrieve them?

Comment: That is may because activercord is which convert 0 to false but when you say .where(enabled: 0) that is handled by your database itself postgres or whatever you use, so it do the query searching for 0 not false.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `change_column_default` to change default to false, and after allow each 0 to be false for old records:

```
def up
  change_column_default :jobs, :enabled, false
  Job.where(enabled: 0).update_all(enabled: false)
end

def down
  change_column_default :jobs, :enabled, 0
end
```

Comment: a lot of answers in SO of how to make a default boolean to false said to use  ":boolean, default: 0" why is that?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9605573/what-is-the-proper-way-of-adding-a-default-boolean-value-that-works-in-mysql

Comment: this one is for only changing the default, but change_column if you want to change any others as well, like changing the column name or type or even default as well, if you checked ths link you posted check the answer followed the accepted answer.